In Flutter, how to obtain width in pixels for a given fontSize?
I need to show double result in a TextField in Flutter app. Sometimes the results are so small number that the number is displayed in exponent like 1.123...e-17 . In some cases such results are not fully visible because the back end of the number e.g. the exponent part e-17 gets hidden or out of viewing space of the TextField. I like that for small results exponent is displayed, but some text being out of viewable space is troubling me.
As a solution I plan to write a function to show double numbers with fixed significant digits, if possible for me, yet to try that out. For, now I'm asking this question to ask help regarding the conversion of fontSize to pixels and vice versa programatically. I have manually computed, using two different emulator sizes - small and large, average pixels per figure to 9.17px/figure and 9.07px/figure respectively, where figure includes digits, dot and minus sign. This computation was for a fontSize of 16.0 (pixels?).
